# Replacing overtightened molly bolts

Tags: plaster, anchor, drywall-anchor, patching-drywall, mirror

I’m attempting to hang a 12.5kg mirror on plasterboard using a French cleat fixing. The studs are in the wrong place, so I’ve used three molly bolts. Unfortunately one is spinning (perhaps overtightened?). Moreover, I’m not confident that the other two are properly tight on the other side, as I don’t know what I’m looking for.

Would it be possible for me to neatly remove the bolts and replace them in the same spot with others (otherwise the mirror won’t be positioned correctly). I’m thinking of using snap toggles instead, but I don’t know if this is excessive for 12.5kg.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just push them through into the void? then put new ones in?

Comment: That would be my first idea. However, for the one that is spinning, I need to first somehow get it out (the screw won’t budge) and then I’m worried I’ll have damaged the plaster. Will it still be strong enough to take a new fixing in the same place?

Comment: If you hold the outer edge of the "nut" with pliers, perhaps needle-nose, does the bolt still spin without backing out?

Comment: I agree with DrMoishe, try to grip the edges of the anchor flange and tighten it more (to make the anchor grip). Then, whilst still gripping the flange, unscrew the screw. Back in the day, good quality mollys came with a special little spanner that fit into holes in the flange to keep it from spinning while setting the anchor or otherwise screwing in/out of it. Now it's all Chinese junk...

Comment: If you just push the molly through that will leave a large hole, I try to unscrew Molly’s then push them in so they can then be pulled out. sound crazy?  There are usually 4 thin strips of metal that flair out when a molly is tightened  unscrewing the screw if you can then pushing in on the screw can straighten the tabs enough so it may be able to be removed. I recommend EZ anchors these work as well as Molly’s and can be removed (in some cases they can even work where a molly is punched through). There are metal and plastic ez anchors different sizes. I have no connection but really like them

Comment: There's nothing wrong with sizing up to larger mollybolts.   That 12.5 kilo item might be replaced by something heavier in the future.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've held the nut with my hands fingers and it doesn't move too much, but the bolt won't come out. Although, the nut may be moving more than I can see. I will try with pliers!

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - thanks, will try this suggestion!

Comment: @Criggie - thanks, I suppose i was also wondering whether the wall around the hole will now be compromised for larger fixings.

Comment: @EdBeal - thanks! will take a look at EZ anchors. Do you mean lightly hammer on the screw? Rather than screw it in?

Comment: Yes push the screw will straighten the tabs and then they can be pulled out. Sometimes they break when doing this then the body will pull back through but the tip falls in the wall.

Comment: @drmoishepippik I used the needle nose pliers and held it still, but the bolt still won’t come out. Any idea what’s happened?

Comment: Likely the threaded piece *inside the wall* broke off from the flat part with a hole on the outside of the wall. Try lifting the bolt-head away from that disk, e.g. with a knife blade, and turn the bolt while lifting (and being careful not to cut oneself with the knife). If that doesn't work, then, as others state, hammer the bolt into the wall until it falls down inside, patch the hole, and use an expansion bolt in another place.

Comment: @Drmoishepippik this worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A French Cleat is a piece of wood (or metal) that runs most or all of the width of the object to be hung. It is installed on the surface of the wall, sized to hide behind the object being hung. Unless you're hanging a mirror that's less than 16" wide and the *only* place you *can* hang it happens to be *exactly* between two studs, *some* place on that cleat should cross a stud. If you want to hang it here for aesthetic reasons, then you may want to reconsider the aesthetics for practicality and safety and move the mirror an inch or two one way or the other to find a stud. If, of course, the mirror is more than 16" wide, it should cross a stud *somewhere*. (Note: assumption of US building codes and standard, modern building methodology. If you live outside the US or your house was built prior to 1900, all bets are off.)

Put a proper screw/bolt into the stud, then use mollys/toggle bolts/whatever to prevent the ends from spinning around the central support point.

One good screw/bolt should be able to support your 12 Kg load, so any additional attachment points are bonus weight bearing support in addition to their "anti-tip" job.

Comment: Excelent:  For places where you can not hit the stud use Toggler anchors.   https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831

Answer (score 0):

If the wall's a bit damaged already, consider going all the way, cutting out some drywall/plaster, and then installing a wooden backing board between studs.

You'll then need to patch the drywall/gib and then tape and plaster/mud the joins.  This is followed by sanding and more sanding, then priming and painting (or whatever the finish is)

On the plus side, the work will be at a convenient height above the floor, which is comfortable.  Your plastering work will end up mostly behind the mirror too, so harder to see imperfections.  And the final product will probably hold much more weight safely.

You might also use this access to run some power or ethernet cables to the room through the wall, or even add some noise-reduction/insulation to the accessible voids.

This is more for TVs that can get really heavy, and may be slightly overkill for a mirror.  But you'll know its done right and will last for decades.